# Create a dictionary using input from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file with the following format:

```
Barcelona   2015,2016,2017
Real Madrid   2010
Napoli   2007,2009
Bayern Munich   2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013
```

I want to save this to a dictionary having the team and next a list with the numbers. How can I make this? I have some difficulties in splitting because some teams have bigger names.

Comment: What've you tried?

Comment: Are the team names / numbers separated by tabs or some set number of spaces? Either way regular expressions seem appropriate here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Getting around the comment blocker I see. *Comments cannot contain the content `What have you tried?`:

If the author didn't show what was tried, why do you assume they tried anything? Either ask for a specific bit of information, suggest a specific improvement, or downvote and move on.*

Comment: @Drise Shhhh, they mustn't know ... ;/

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ IMHO, asking OP to include their ugly solution( it's almost sure, otherwise they won't ask ) only add noise to the question, it's not good for google or future visitor.

Comment: @liliscent, this is a great Meta question. The consensus usually is that it helps (a) catch common pitfalls, (b) suggest the level of explanation required in the answer. For example, if the user is adept at regex, a regex-based answer *may* be appropriate.

Comment: @liliscent I wholeheartedly disagree. Usually, it is not good form to reward askers who have not put in any effort whatsoever into solving their problem first. I tend to give users the benefit of the doubt before downvoting and voting to close first. You're free to follow a different principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, pure-python solution, which is

- non-regex
- not a one liner
- *very* readable

```
data = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        city, dates = line.rstrip().rsplit(None, 1)
        data[city] = [int(d) for d in dates.split(',')]
```

```
data
{
    "Barcelona": [
        2015,
        2016,
        2017
    ],
    "Real Madrid": [
        2010
    ],
    "Napoli": [
        2007,
        2009
    ],
    "Bayern Munich": [
        2008,
        2009,
        2010,
        2011,
        2012,
        2013
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the Pandas solution, assuming 4-space delimiter.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""Barcelona   2015,2016,2017
Real Madrid   2010
Napoli   2007,2009
Bayern Munich   2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delimiter='   ', header=None, names=['Club', 'Years'])

df['Years'] = [list(map(int, x)) for x in df['Years'].str.split(',')]
d = df.set_index('Club')['Years'].to_dict()
```

**Result**

```
{'Barcelona': [2015, 2016, 2017],
 'Bayern Munich': [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
 'Napoli': [2007, 2009],
 'Real Madrid': [2010]}
```

**Explanation**

- Read file with appropriate delimiter and name columns.
- Split by comma and map each element to integer type via list comprehension.
- Create series indexed by Club and use `.to_dict()` to output dictionary.

Comment: what's the advantage of using pandas over just reading the file into a list, etc?

Comment: You could write a loop with a split function and it would be faster for the simple reason that it doesn't have a fraction of the overhead that pandas would. Also, readability is moot here considering the other solutions are unreadable because of the authors and not the inherent nature of the solution itself.

Comment: Write a solution then, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, and I'll upvote it if I find it more readable :). That's how this site works.

Comment: I'm never a fan of adding in unneeded libraries in a question where it wasn't explicitly asked for. See every C++ question I've asked where the answer was "Just use `Boost`...". OP may not be able to access external libraries. For instance I cannot access `pandas` on my config controlled work machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` to split each line at space spanning the team name and the first digit:

```
import re
final_d = {a:map(int, b.split(',')) for a, b in map(lambda x:re.split('\s+(?=\d)', x.strip('\n')), open('filename.txt').readlines())}
```

Output:

```
{'Real Madrid': [2010], 'Bayern Munich': [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013], 'Barcelona': [2015, 2016, 2017], 'Napoli': [2007, 2009]}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this,

```
file = open('file_name')
d = {}
for line in file.readlines():
   try:
       key, value = line.replace('\n','').split('\t') ##if your sep == '\t'
   except ValueError:
       pass ### if line is empty
   else: ### if all is ok
       d[key] = value
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, I don't know if it's what you want though.

```
file=open("info.txt", "r")
lines1=file.readlines()
lines=[]
for i in lines1:
    lines.append(i.split("   "))
output={}
for i in lines:
    key=i[0]
    exec("item=("+i[1]+")")
    output[key]=item
```

Comment: lines1 is so that you can then format it differently